# C# SendKeys.SendWait to a dialog of another Process (notepad.exe)

Tags: c#, .net, sendkeys, sharpdevelop

I'm trying to do the following in C#:

- Open a new process (notepad.exe)
- Enter some text (using SendKeys)
- Close Notepad (deal with any confirmation dialogs)

Here's what I got

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.Filename = "notepad.exe";
p.Start();

// use the user32.dll SetForegroundWindow method
SetForegroundWindow( p.MainWindowHandle ); // make sure notepad has focus

SendKeys.SendWait( "some text" );

SendKeys.SendWait( "%f" ); // send ALT+f
SendKeys.SendWait( "x" ); // send x = exit

// a confirmation dialog appears
```

All this works just as expected, but now after I've sent ALT+f+x I get a
"Do you want to save changed to Untitled" dialog and I would like to close it from within
my applications by "pressing" 'n' for "Don't Save". However

```
SendKeys.SendWait( "n" );
```

works only if my application has not lost focus (after ALT+f+x). If it did and I try to go back using

```
SetForegroundWindow( p.MainWindowHandle );
```

this sets the focus to the main notepad window instead of the confirmation dialog. I used the `GetForegroundWindow` method from user32.dll and found out that the dialog handle is different than the notepad handle (which kinda makes sence) but `SetForegroundWindow` doesn't work with even with the dialog window handle

Any idea how I can give the focus back to the dialog so that I can successfully use `SendKeys`?

here's the full code

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);        

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();             

[DllImport("User32.DLL")] 
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow); 

public const int SW_RESTORE = 9;        

    ...

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
p.Start();
Thread.Sleep( 1000 );

SendKeys.SendWait( "some text" );
SendKeys.SendWait( "%f" ); // send ALT+F
SendKeys.SendWait( "x" ); // send x = exit

IntPtr dialogHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine( "notepad handle: " + p.MainWindowHandle );
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine( "dialog handle: " + dialogHandle );

Thread.Sleep( 5000 ); // switch to a different application to lose focus

SetForegroundWindow( p.MainWindowHandle );
ShowWindow( dialogHandle, SW_RESTORE );

Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
SendKeys.SendWait( "n" );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't give what you don't have - `SetForegroundWindow()` only works if your application currently has the focus.

Modern Windows versions prevent applications from stealing focus, as that was a major annoyance back in the Windows 9x days.

Also, 'Alt+F, x' only refers to exit on English Windows versions, it won't work on most other languages. Avoid using `SendKeys()`, it's impossible to use in a reliable way.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense. I'm left with `SendKeys` because my application needs to automate user inputs in another 3rd party application.

p.s. I've used the ALT+F x only for demonstration here