# Close a dialog programmatically after running an executable

Tags: c#, process, window

I have a .EXE that performs several calculations and was implemented by another company. I do not have access to the source code of this executable and it is out of question trying to modify its behaviour.

My problem is:

I am writing a code in c# to call this EXE and read its file output. After the EXE is done with the calculation, it opens a MessageBox -> "Calculation Done", and only after clicking in a "OK Button" the output file is written. That really sucks, since it is necessary the user manually click with the mouse to close the MessageBox. I am wondering if it is possible to close this MessageBox programmatically?

I have googled it and my guess is that is it possible using [MainWindowHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle), but I am not sure. Any help?

Comment: That is the only solution as far as i know, mixed with `SendKeys`.

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522540/close-a-messagebox-after-several-seconds/14522952#14522952)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The OP said that it can't modify the other exe and i don't see the utility of what you linked in *his* app.

Comment: @AsadAli Who asked OP to modify the code. Accepted answer should work cross process.

Comment: Thanks @AsadAli. I will try Process.GetProcesses()[0].CloseMainWindow();

Comment: [This will Help full to you  ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522540/close-a-messagebox-after-several-seconds

either create dynamic window with timer.

Comment: @guilhermecgs [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314524/c-sharp-sendkeys-sendwait-to-a-dialog-of-another-process-notepad-exe) is your identical case, give it a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `FindWindow` to locate your `MessageBox`, and then use `SendMessage` to send a close message

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd,uint Msg,int wParam,int lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")] 
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lp1, string lp2);

public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

IntPtr window = FindWindow(null, "MessageBox Title Here");
if (window != IntPtr.Zero)
{
   SendMessage(window, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);  
}
```

Read more [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mrmohankumar/find-and-close-the-window-using-win-api/)

Comment: One suggestion: the first parameter to `SendMessage` should be `IntPtr` rather than int (the first parameter of `SendMessage` is `HWND`, which is `void*`); the handle can then be passed directly to `SendMessage` without a cast.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice. Updated my answer.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, perfect solution. I have tested and it works.

Comment: I recommend using this answer with spyxx.exe tool present in .NET SDK